# Writing the contents of an ObservableCollection to a text file

Tags: c#, wpf, file-io, observablecollection

The goal of this question is to find out a way to obtain specific contents of an `ObservableCollection` (`strings` to be specific), and write them to a text file.

This collection is structured by using nodes because it is used to implement a `TreeView`. With that being said I am currently trying to obtain the child values of a parent node like so:

```
// I am currently getting an InvalidOperationException -- Sequence contains no matching element
var Node = Collection.GetAllChildren(x => x.Children)
                     .Distinct().ToList()
                     .First(x => x.DisplayName == Name);
```

In order to write to the file I am using this `File.` method: `File.WriteAllLines()`. It is my understanding that this method takes the FileName, and then an `IEnumerable` (a `List`, etc.). Does `ObservableCollection` contain a method that is `IEnumerable` compatible or do I need to add the contents to a `List`?

Right now I am trying this for the write to file line:

```
File.WriteAllLines(FileName, new ObservableCollection<string> { ViewModel.Data.ToList() });
```

How can I correct these two detrimental parts of my code? What is the correct way to get the information I need, and then add it to the file?

**Update:** These are the current errors that I receive on the above^ line of code. If I am implementing this correctly (which I am, based on the answers), why am I receiving these compile errors? (note: `type` has been switched to `string`)

**Update 2:** I've updated the argument to be written to the file. `Data` is an `ObservableCollection<ViewModel>`.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, an overload of `File.WriteAllLines` takes `IEnumerable<string>`. `ObservableCollection<string>` implements `IEnumerable<string>`, so things should work.

Just `Type` should be `string`:

```
File.WriteAllLines(FileName, new ObservableCollection<Type> ( NodeName.ToList() ));
```

> Does ObservableCollection contain a method that is IEnumberable
>   compatible

No, it *implements* IEnumerable.

P.S. As it is suggested in another answer, `ObservableCollection` is redundant. You may pass anything which implements `IEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: Okay, I should be implementing this correctly now based on your answer. However, I still receive compile errors. Please take a look at my update.

Comment: @Eric Firstly, if `ObservableCollection<string>` is constructed with a list argument, the syntax should be `new ObservableCollection<string>(list)`, with round brackets, see my last edit. But please note, as Kaz-LA mentioned, that you can use a list as is, without wrapping it with `ObservableCollection`. Secondly, the error suggests that we do not deal with `List<string>`, but with `List<HierarchicalVM>`. What is the type of `NodeName`? Are you sure that compilation error caused by the line you mentioned?

Comment: It's actually like this: `File.WriteAllLines(FileName, new ObservableCollection<string> { ViewModel.ObservableCollection<HierarchicalVM>.ToList() });`

Comment: @Eric Oh, it should be a list of strings, not list of view models.

Comment: Well, the `ObservableCollection` that I am using is of type `<ViewModel>`

Comment: @Eric Understood. But you cannot write view models using `File.WriteAllLines`, you write strings, correct? What do you want to write to the file for every view model?

Comment: Yes, so I need to call it's `DisplayName` then (because that's what I want it to write to the file)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46959/discussion-between-eric-after-dark-and-alexd)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the signature of System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(), it accepts an array of strings or an IEnumerable of strings;

Try this:

```
File.WriteAllLines(FileName, NodeName.ToList());
```